# How to change the value of hidden text input box when select menu option is changed

Tags: reactjs, components, dropdown, hidden

I want to change the existing value in a hidden text input box (automatically when the box is closed) to an empty string ('') when the user chooses one of the drop down menu selections. The problem is that I can close the component with the right menu selection, but the value does not change to an empty string until I click the button a second time. Then the value becomes an empty string and I get the correct information.

I originally based the approach to that of form data being passed to/from the parent and that does not seem to work for this component. I tried using a setState() function, however, this either didn't take or I did not implement correctly. All state has been set and all other components move data around as they're supposed to.

This is the parent component that sends/receives the information from the . The "cost={dailyTransportationCost}" is supposed to send the new value to the child.

```
<DailyTransportationCost   
    cost={dailyTransportationCost}
    handleTransportationCost={e => setDailyTransportationCost(e.target.value)}
/>
```

This is the component that needs to change to an empty string when it's closed based on the  menu option (separate component)

```
const DailyTransportationCost = ({ cost, handleTransportationCost }) => {


   return (
     <div className={`${styles.containerTransportationCost}`}>

    <label className={`${styles.containerLabel}`}    htmlFor='dailyTransportationCost'>Daily Cost</label>
    <input className={`${styles.containerInput}`}
         placeholder='0.00'
         id='dailyTransportationCost'
         type='number'
             value={cost.dailyTransportationCost}
         onChange={handleTransportationCost}
    />
     </div>
     );
};
```

Thank you for your help. I've been banging around on this for a couple of days. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

me again...
I figured it out. It was a simple useEffect() and everything worked remarkably well. Just want to thank anyone who might have stopped by.

Cheers!